# Python PIL image.frombytes throws a ValueError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Im trying to convert raw image data to a png with PIL so i can save it.
The raw data has the form of a string with each character representing a byte of the image file (3 characters per pixel r g b )

my code looks something like this

```
from PIL import Image as img

def convert(str_data, size):
    pic = img.frombytes("RGB", size, bytes(str_data, 'utf-8'))
    pic.save("image.png")
```

and my stacktrace looks like this

```
File "/home/main.py", line 4, in convert
  pic = img.frombytes("RGB", size, bytes(str_data, 'utf-8'))
File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2671, in frombytes
  im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 800, in frombytes
  raise VauleError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

If there is anything missing from here pls inform me so i can add it.

here is the size, type of str_data, first 10 characters of str_data and len(str_data) as requested

```
(1920, 955)
<class 'str'>
       
1375200
```

the contents of str_data happen to be 0 because of whats being sent from the source.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `size`? What is the type of `str_data`, i.e. `type(str_data)` ? What are the first 10 bytes of `str_data`, i.e. `str_data[:10]`? What is the length of `str_data`? How would `str_data` look if your image was two pixels in size, one red pixel and one green one?

Comment: size is coming from an external source just like the str_data
i can print out all of that but i dont know where it would be usefull

Comment: If your image is 1920x955 it must have 1_833_600 pixels, correct? If the pixels are RGB, there will be 3 bytes for each of those 1_833_600 pixels so you will need 5_500_800 bytes, but you only have 1_375_200 or 1/4 of the pixels you need.

Comment: the data seems to be reaching my proxy at least 5242880 bytes of it

Comment: Could you check the size of `bytes(str_data, 'utf-8')`? Because your string is made up of all possible byte values it's possible that the length check on the string is seeing unicode sequences in there that make multiple bytes appear to be a single character. (Assuming my understanding of such things is right.) Packing data into strings is a bit fraught really - the image data should be bytes from the start ideally.

Comment: the main problem with that is that the image doesnt come from a python context its being transmitted with http in a json string containing the string which is isolated and then assigned to str_data

Comment: Is there an extra layer of encoding like base64 or such? Because dumping raw binary data into json is certainly an... interesting approach. If it's compressed and then encoded it would certainly account for it being much smaller than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt really figure it out but I found another way "around" the problem.
I edited the source of the image so it encodes it into a png before its sent to me.